# How to solve : "Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Resource is not in the state certificateValidated"? CDK

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-cdk, amazon-certificate-manager

I have the following error trying to create a static website inspired by https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/static-site/static-site.ts

```
 const certificateArn = new acm.DnsValidatedCertificate(
          this,
          "SiteCertificateR53",
          {
              domainName: props.siteDomain,
              hostedZone: props.zone,
              region: "us-east-1", // Cloudfront only checks this region for certificates.
            }
        ).certificateArn;
 
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "CertificateR53", {value: certificateArn});
```

Error:

Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Resource is not in the state certificateValidated

Comment: There is an open issue for the problem: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2914

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to do cross region stuff (e.g. `us-east-1` needs a resource from `us-west-2`) using the following method provides the same benefit as `DnsValidatedCertificate`

```
const certificate = new acm.Certificate(this, `SiteCertificateR53`, {
            domainName: props.siteDomain,
            validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(props.zone)});
```

If you still gotta do cross-region stuff, then you should create and deploy your zone via AWS console first. That won't guarantee a fix though, this page can help if you're still stuck:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html